# Why my swap function swaps is in place?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
    def swap(array, i):
        array[i], array[(i+1)%len(array)] = array[(i+1)%len(array)], array[i]
        return array
```

Why my swap functions swap in place?
I mean in the swap function 'array' is local variable and i am swapping the elements of the local variable and returning the 'array' then why changes is made in the list i pass.
for example if there i a list `a = [1,2,3,4]` after calling `swap(a,0)` it should return `[2,1,3,4]` which it does but it also modifying the list 'a' i passed?

Comment: Because lists are mutable. You are passing `array` as a list and performing a swap, which modifies it in-place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) (see the accepted answer for a complete explanation of your issue)

Comment: Lists are pointers to a memory location. You need to perform a copy operation or it will act on the same chunk of memory no matter what function space it is in. list_copy = original_list[:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, like many object oriented languages, passes function arguments *by sharing*, rather than by copying.

You should think of `array` as a label to a specific bit of memory. If your function `def f(a)` takes a variable called `a`, whenever you call `swap(some_variable)`, the memory which stores `some_variable` becomes available inside your function with the label `a`.

This is why the variable is changed in your example. If you want to leave the original value of `array` unchanged, you need to first copy it, like in the code below.

```
def swap(original_array, i):
    # use list() return a copy of the list
    new_array = list(original_array)
    # do work on the copy of the list, which is a local var
    new_array[i], new_array[(i+1)%len(new_array)] = new_array[(i+1)%len(new_array)], new_array[i]
    # return the value of the local var
    return new_array 

# setup a list
a = [1,2,3,4]
# function still works
assert swap(a, 2) == [1,2,4,3]
# but it does not change the value passed to it
assert a = [1,2,3,4]
# and its local variable new_array is not available in this scope
assert 'new_array' not in dir()
```